# Convert PDF to JPG without Imagemagick

Tags: php, unix, pdf, jpeg

Is there a way to convert a common UTF-8 encoded PDF to a JPG without using ImageMagick or Ghostscript?

The reason I'm asking is, that I have to replace or "simply" double layer a small part (date) of a PDF document. I don't want to install all that stuff for it and wonder if there is a different way to do it.

Sadly Google couldn't give me an anwser so I decided to give SU a chance.

Comment: Why is it migrated here? The question is about PHP, so it belong on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit the resulting image file, you will need an image editor. If you are on a UNIX platform, that will probably be [`gimp`](http://www.gimp.org/).

If so, you're in luck, `gimp` can handle PDFs, just open the file directly in `gimp`, edit it and save as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Mac OS X, just open it in Preview and then use Save As to export it as a JPEG. If you're not on OS X, perhaps you could edit your question to provide a lot more detail about your environment -- what kind of Unix are you using, what distribution, what packages do you have installed, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GIMP, Adobe Photoshop, Adobe Acrobat ( > Save as JPG, JPEG).
Or you can use the Online Converter as Stefan mentioned if the document is not  private, sensitive.

Comment: Listing tools that can help in the process doesn't really explain how to accomplish what was asked.  Can you expand your answer, or at least describe what makes the mentioned tools better for the task than random Google hits?  Good guidance on recommending products here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not to be done dynamically you can do that "by hand".
Every good PDF Printer does that. For example Bullzip or PDF24. 
If you want to do it in a script, maybe you can also use one of the various online converters like http://pdf2jpg.net/ for instance.